# How to override root environment variable in anaconda

Tags: linux, anaconda

I create two separate environments(for example: one is tf, other is caffe) in my linux via `conda create -n XX python=2.7`. I add some paths to environment variables in `.bashrc` like `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH`. Now I want to use `cuda-7.5` in the tf environment. How could I realize that every time I activate the tf environment, it automatically override the `cuda-8.0` in `.bashrc` and set the `cuda-7.5` in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: One possibilty: create a shell script that exports the PATH variable and calls `source activate XX`. Then create an alias in your bashrc setting `activate_XX` to `source <path/to/your/shellscript.sh>`. You can then activate your environment by typing activate_XX and the path will be set correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it is really one possible way. I just have tried the method [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#saved-environment-variables). I set `PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5:$PATH` in the `env_vars.sh` and it seems to work too. Actually it doesn't override the `cuda-8.0`and it just place `cuda-7.5` before `cuda-8.0` so that `cuda-7.5` can be searched firstly.